# Can TikZ create pixel art images?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can you create images like this:

[image]

when you have something like

```
0 = green (#54ff00)
1 = white (#ffffff)
2 = red   (#ff0000)
3 = blue  (#0048ff)

Image (Python list of integers defined above):
[[2,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,3,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,3,2,1,1,0,0],
 [0,3,2,2,2,1,1],
 [0,3,2,0,0,1,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,1,0]]
```

with TikZ?

### How far I got

The following MWE defines all colors, produces a grid of the correct size (though the size is determined by hand):

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \newcommand\n{7}
    \definecolor{green}{HTML}{54FF00}
    \definecolor{wite}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
    \definecolor{red}{HTML}{FF0000}
    \definecolor{blue}{HTML}{0048FF}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \x in {1,...,\n}{
            \foreach \y in {1,...,\n}{
                \begin{scope}[shift={(\x,\y)}]
                  \draw [fill=green] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
                \end{scope}
            }
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Of course, I could simpy make a lot of adjusted

```
                \begin{scope}[shift={(\x,\y)}]
                  \draw [fill=green] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
                \end{scope}
```

but I've wondered if this can (with reasonable effort) be done in TikZ / LaTeX.

My problem is giving TikZ the color array. I don't have any idea how to do this.
I only know two types of looks in TikZ:

```
\foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4,5}{...}
\foreach \number in {1,...,\n}{...}
```

I have never seen a nested over a 2D-array. All I have seen so far were 1D-Arrays of tuples (with fixed tuple size).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is a completely different approach from my other answer, and this one takes as its input, a form similar to that mentioned by the OP, namely:

```
\def\map{
[[2,0,0,0,0,0,0]
 [0,3,0,0,0,0,0]
 [0,3,2,1,1,0,0]
 [0,3,2,2,2,1,1]
 [0,3,2,0,0,1,0]
 [0,0,0,0,0,1,0]
 [0,0,0,0,0,1,0]]
}
```

In this case, this argument is passed to the macro `\boxart`.  The box size is set with `\setlength{\boxsize}{}`.

EDIT: The OP has asked for a clarification on the code internals of `\boxart`.  In this routine, I use some macros from the `stringstrings` package to strip out left brackets, turn commas into spaces, and turn right brackets into " . " strings.  The result is a space-separated string (`\thestring`), that will look like

```
2 0 0 0 0 0 0 . 0 3 0     etc.
```

The `\getargsC` macro from `readarray` knows how to efficiently read space-delimited strings and is fed this string.  The number of arguments in the string is stored in `\narg` and each argument is stored individually in `\argi`, `\argii`, `\argiii`, etc.  Once that is done, a loop is set up (to go through `\narg` iterations, once for each item in `\thestring`), and each argument is checked.  If it is a `0`, a `\gr` is issued for a green block, and so on for `1`, `2`, and `3`.  If a `.` is found, a `\par` (paragraph) is issued.  This while loop is performed inside a `\parbox`, so that the local line spacing can be set and the result doesn't have to start in the left column of the document (I should point out that the `\parbox` width was set arbitrarily by me, and may need to be manually tweaked by the user).

For the OP's edification, an `\edef` is an assignment where the contents of the argument are fully *expanded* before being assigned.  Thus, what is found in `\clr` are the individual items from `\thestring` successively stored in the `\arg...` variables: `\argi` is `2`, `\argii` is `0`, ..., `\argviii` is `.`, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\usepackage{readarray}
\newlength\boxsize
\setlength\boxsize{1ex}
\def\block#1{\fboxsep=0pt\fbox{\color{#1}\rule{\boxsize}{\boxsize}}\kern-\fboxrule}
\def\gr{\block{green}}
\def\rd{\block{red}}
\def\bl{\block{blue}}
\def\wh{\block{white}}
\newcounter{index}%
\newcommand\boxart[1]{%
  \setcounter{index}{0}%
  \convertchar[q]{#1}{,}{ }%
  \convertchar[q]{\thestring}{[}{}%
  \convertchar[q]{\thestring}{]}{ . }%
  \getargsC{\thestring}%
  \parbox[b]{8ex}{%
    \baselineskip\boxsize%
    \parindent 0ex%
    \parskip -.2\boxsize%
    \addtolength{\parskip}{-2\fboxrule}%
    \whiledo{%
      \theindex < \narg}{%
      \stepcounter{index}%
      \edef\clr{\csname arg\romannumeral\theindex\endcsname}%
      \expandafter\if\clr0\gr\fi%
      \expandafter\if\clr1\wh\fi%
      \expandafter\if\clr2\rd\fi%
      \expandafter\if\clr3\bl\fi%
     \expandafter\if\clr.\par\fi%
    }%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
%0 = green (#54ff00)
%1 = white (#ffffff)
%2 = red   (#ff0000)
%3 = blue  (#0048ff)
\def\map{
[[2,0,0,0,0,0,0]
 [0,3,0,0,0,0,0]
 [0,3,2,1,1,0,0]
 [0,3,2,2,2,1,1]
 [0,3,2,0,0,1,0]
 [0,0,0,0,0,1,0]
 [0,0,0,0,0,1,0]]
}
Here it is: \boxart{\map}

\def\map{
[[2,0,0,0,0]
 [0,3,0,0,0]
 [0,3,2,0,0]
 [0,3,2,1,1]
 [0,3,0,1,0]]
}
\setlength{\boxsize}{1.2ex}
Another: \boxart{\map}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: Very neet indeed!

Answer (score 45):

Here is a very simple solution using TikZ:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\def\pixels{
  {2,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,3,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,3,2,1,1,0,0},
  {0,3,2,2,2,1,1},
  {0,3,2,0,0,1,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,1,0}%
}
\definecolor{pixel 0}{HTML}{54FF00}
\definecolor{pixel 1}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\definecolor{pixel 2}{HTML}{FF0000}
\definecolor{pixel 3}{HTML}{0048FF}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \line [count=\y] in \pixels {
    \foreach \pix [count=\x] in \line {
      \draw[fill=pixel \pix] (\x,-\y) rectangle +(1,1);
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for simplicity (finally an answer I understand completely and that might help me to create other stuff :-) )

Comment: The better solution ! bravo !!

Comment: Is there any way to set default `\pix` value (I mean, if it cannot value anything in the matrix, it will fill with, say, red)?

Comment: @pushpen.paul There is no matrix. It's just a list of lists. The `\pix` macro is just an item from a list. If one item is empty, the `\pix` macro is empty and the color `pixel ` (with a space at the end) is used (it's like a _default_ color).

Answer (score 20):

A `matrix of nodes` could be an option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{ 
table/.style={
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={rectangle,draw=black,minimum size=1cm,align=center},
  nodes in empty cells
  }
}

\definecolor{0}{HTML}{54FF00}
\definecolor{1}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\definecolor{2}{HTML}{FF0000}
\definecolor{3}{HTML}{0048FF}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix (mat) [table]
{
|[fill=2]| & |[fill=0]|  & |[fill=0]| & |[fill=0]| & |[fill=0]| & |[fill=0]| & |[fill=0]| \\
|[fill=0]| & |[fill=3]|  & |[fill=0]| & |[fill=0]| & |[fill=0]| & |[fill=0]| & |[fill=0]| \\
|[fill=0]| & |[fill=3]|  & |[fill=2]| & |[fill=1]| & |[fill=1]| & |[fill=0]| & |[fill=0]| \\
|[fill=0]| & |[fill=3]|  & |[fill=2]| & |[fill=2]| & |[fill=2]| & |[fill=1]| & |[fill=1]| \\
|[fill=0]| & |[fill=3]|  & |[fill=2]| & |[fill=0]| & |[fill=0]| & |[fill=1]| & |[fill=0]| \\
|[fill=0]| & |[fill=0]|  & |[fill=0]| & |[fill=0]| & |[fill=0]| & |[fill=0]| & |[fill=0]| \\
|[fill=0]| & |[fill=0]|  & |[fill=0]| & |[fill=0]| & |[fill=0]| & |[fill=0]| & |[fill=0]| \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Or, even shorter, selecting the dominant color as default:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{0}{HTML}{54FF00}
\definecolor{1}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\definecolor{2}{HTML}{FF0000}
\definecolor{3}{HTML}{0048FF}

\tikzset{ 
table/.style={
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={rectangle,draw=black,fill=0,minimum size=1cm,align=center},
  nodes in empty cells
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix (mat) [table]
{
|[fill=2]| &   &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & |[fill=3]|  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & |[fill=3]|  & |[fill=2]| & |[fill=1]| & |[fill=1]| &  &  \\
 & |[fill=3]|  & |[fill=2]| & |[fill=2]| & |[fill=2]| & |[fill=1]| & |[fill=1]| \\
 & |[fill=3]|  & |[fill=2]| &  &  & |[fill=1]| &  \\
 &   &  &  &  &  &  \\
 &   &  &  &  &  &  \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And with a slight (though a little slow) help from `pgfplotstable`

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{%
2,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,3,0,0,0,0,0
0,3,2,1,1,0,0
0,3,2,2,2,1,1
0,3,2,0,0,1,0
0,0,0,0,0,1,0
0,0,0,0,0,1,0
}\mycolortable
\newcommand\n{7}
\definecolor{c0}{HTML}{54FF00}
\definecolor{c1}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\definecolor{c2}{HTML}{FF0000}
\definecolor{c3}{HTML}{0048FF}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x[count=\xi from 0] in {1,...,\n}{
        \foreach \y[count=\yi from 0] in {1,...,\n}{
            \begin{scope}[shift={(\x,-\y)}]
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\yi}{\xi}\of{\mycolortable}
            \draw[ultra thick,fill=c\pgfplotsretval] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
            \end{scope}
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've added a similar example, Gonzalo. I couldn't resist :)

Comment: @percusse by all means! Great addition.

Comment: for the pgfplotstable-part: Can you get the size of the table automatically? By the way, it does not have to be a square.

Comment: @moose All three options will allow arbitrary rectangular shapes: in the first two, simply fill the matrix of nodes with as many rows and columns as required; in the third one (`pgfplotstable`), define `\m` to control the rows and use `\m` and `\n` on the nested cycles. Regarding the question about the size of the table, I am not sure what you are asking. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Ok, I try to make clear what I mean: I think it should not be necessary to define `\n` (or `\m`) excplicitly. These parameters are implicitly given by the information within `pgfplotstableread` (for example: `2,0,0,0,0,0,0\n2,0,0,0,0,0,0` is `\m=2` and `\n=7`).

Answer (score 10):

Make a stack (without tikz):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\block#1{\kern-\fboxrule\fboxsep=0pt\fbox{\color{#1}\rule{1ex}{1ex}}}
\def\gr{\block{green}}
\def\rd{\block{red}}
\def\bl{\block{blue}}
\def\wh{\block{white}}
\setstackgap{S}{-\fboxrule}
\begin{document}
\Shortstack{
\rd\gr\gr\gr\gr\gr\gr\\
\gr\bl\gr\gr\gr\gr\gr\\
\gr\bl\rd\wh\wh\gr\gr\\
\gr\bl\rd\rd\rd\wh\wh\\
\gr\bl\rd\gr\gr\wh\gr\\
\gr\gr\gr\gr\gr\wh\gr\\
\gr\gr\gr\gr\gr\wh\gr
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I have found this question just by surfing TeX.SX, and I thought I'll post an answer not recreating the questioner's figure, but the [Arecibo message](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arecibo_message) that I have “typesetted” a while ago in TikZ and LuaLaTeX.

[image]

In the code I'm only iterating over a huge two-dimensional array which contains the “message”, and creating nodes according to the values at a given index.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nohead,%
    nofoot,%
    nomarginpar,%
    paperwidth=210mm,%
    paperheight=297mm,%
    tmargin=5mm,%
    rmargin=5mm,%
    bmargin=5mm,%
    lmargin=5mm,
    vscale=1,%
    hscale=1]{geometry}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{luacode}

\newlength{\zeropt}
\setlength{\zeropt}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\zeropt}
\setlength{\parindent}{\zeropt}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{\zeropt}

\tikzset{%
    cell/.style={%
        minimum size=0.35cm%
    }%
}
\tikzset{%
    one/.style={%
        fill=White%
    },%
    two/.style={%
        fill=DarkOrchid!50!Fuchsia%
    },%
    three/.style={%
        fill=LimeGreen%
    },%
    four/.style={%
        fill=Blue!65!Cyan%
    },%
    five/.style={%
        fill=Crimson!50!Red%
    },%
    six/.style={%
        fill=Gold!50!Yellow%
    }%
}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{luacode*}
    arecibo_message = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0},
        {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0},
        {3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {3, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 3, 0},
        {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3},
        {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0},
        {3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {3, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 3, 0},
        {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3},
        {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0},
        {0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0},
        {0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 0, 5, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 5, 5, 5, 0, 5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
        {0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 6, 0, 6, 0, 6, 0, 6, 0, 6},
        {0, 0, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 6, 0, 6, 0, 6, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0}}

    function print_message(message)
        local cols = #message[1]
        local rows = #message

        tex.sprint([[\begin{tikzpicture}]])

        for j = 1, cols do
            for i = 1, rows do
                if message[i][j] == 1 then
                    tex.sprint([[\node[cell, one] at (]])
                elseif message[i][j] == 2 then
                    tex.sprint([[\node[cell, two] at (]])
                elseif message[i][j] == 3 then
                    tex.sprint([[\node[cell, three] at (]])
                elseif message[i][j] == 4 then
                    tex.sprint([[\node[cell, four] at (]])
                elseif message[i][j] == 5 then
                    tex.sprint([[\node[cell, five] at (]])
                elseif message[i][j] == 6 then
                    tex.sprint([[\node[cell, six] at (]])
                end

                if message[i][j] ~= 0 then
                    tex.sprint(0.35 * (j - 1))
                    tex.sprint([[cm,]])
                    tex.sprint(0.35 * (-i + 1))
                    tex.sprint([[cm){};]])
                end
            end
        end

        tex.sprint([[\end{tikzpicture}]])

    end
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{Black}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
\luadirect{print_message(arecibo_message)}
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

A solution with PSTricks, just for fun!

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfmath} % it must be explicitly loaded!

\def\pixels{
  {2,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,3,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,3,2,1,1,0,0},
  {0,3,2,2,2,1,1},
  {0,3,2,0,0,1,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,1,0}%
}
\definecolor{pixel 0}{HTML}{54FF00}
\definecolor{pixel 1}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\definecolor{pixel 2}{HTML}{FF0000}
\definecolor{pixel 3}{HTML}{0048FF}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[fillstyle=solid,dimen=monkey](7,-7)
    \foreach \line [count=\y from 0] in \pixels 
    {
        \foreach \pix [count=\x from 0] in \line 
        {
            \rput(\x,-\y){\psframe[fillcolor=pixel \pix](1,-1)}
        }
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I really got surprised to know that color names can contain spaces.

Comment: `dimen` key provides 3 options with primate names: `indri` for inner, `monkey` for middle, and `orangutan` for outer.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about the black lines, you can use a simple `\rule` to mimic a pixel and then use the `picture` environment. I guess it's not *exactly* what you had in mind but just in case, here you go:

```
 \documentclass{minimal}

 %Pixel macro and its dimension
 \newcommand{\dimension}{10pt}
 \newcommand{\pixel}[2]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{#2}{#2}}}


 %Colors
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \definecolor{couleura}{RGB}{255, 0, 0}
 \definecolor{couleurb}{RGB}{84, 255, 0}
 \definecolor{couleurc}{RGB}{0, 72, 255}
 \definecolor{couleurd}{RGB}{255, 255, 255}

 %Colored pixels
 \newcommand{\pixela}{\pixel{couleura}{\dimension}}
 \newcommand{\pixelb}{\pixel{couleurb}{\dimension}}
 \newcommand{\pixelc}{\pixel{couleurc}{\dimension}}
 \newcommand{\pixeld}{\pixel{couleurd}{\dimension}}

 \begin{document}

 \setlength{\unitlength}{\dimension}%
 \begin{picture}(7,7)%
     \put (0,7) {\pixela}%
     \put (1,7) {\pixelb}%
     \put (2,7) {\pixelb}%
     \put (3,7) {\pixelb}%
     \put (4,7) {\pixelb}%
     \put (5,7) {\pixelb}%
     \put (6,7) {\pixelb}%
     \put (0,6) {\pixelb}%
     \put (1,6) {\pixelc}%
     \put (2,6) {\pixelb}%
     \put (3,6) {\pixelb}%
     \put (4,6) {\pixelb}%
     \put (5,6) {\pixelb}%
     \put (6,6) {\pixelb}%
     \put (0,5) {\pixelb}%
     \put (1,5) {\pixelc}%
     \put (2,5) {\pixela}%
     \put (3,5) {\pixeld}%
     \put (4,5) {\pixeld}%
     \put (5,5) {\pixelb}%
     \put (6,5) {\pixelb}%
     \put (0,4) {\pixelb}%
     \put (1,4) {\pixelc}%
     \put (2,4) {\pixela}%
     \put (3,4) {\pixela}%
     \put (4,4) {\pixela}%
     \put (5,4) {\pixeld}%
     \put (6,4) {\pixeld}%
     \put (0,3) {\pixelb}%
     \put (1,3) {\pixelc}%
     \put (2,3) {\pixela}%
     \put (3,3) {\pixelb}%
     \put (4,3) {\pixelb}%
     \put (5,3) {\pixeld}%
     \put (6,3) {\pixelb}%
     \put (0,2) {\pixelb}%
     \put (1,2) {\pixelb}%
     \put (2,2) {\pixelb}%
     \put (3,2) {\pixelb}%
     \put (4,2) {\pixelb}%
     \put (5,2) {\pixelb}%
     \put (6,2) {\pixelb}%
     \put (0,1) {\pixelb}%
     \put (1,1) {\pixelb}%
     \put (2,1) {\pixelb}%
     \put (3,1) {\pixelb}%
     \put (4,1) {\pixelb}%
     \put (5,1) {\pixelb}%
     \put (6,1) {\pixelb}%
  \end{picture}

 \end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Big drawback : the code is very long ! But on the other hand, it's pretty fast. And, if you're lazy, I wrote a python script a little while ago to generate the tex code from a png file (the png needs to have an alpha layer). You can check it out here:

http://alexisfles.ch/en/latex/pixelart.html

Answer (score 2):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\definecolor{green}{HTML}{54FF00}
\definecolor{white}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\definecolor{red}{HTML}{FF0000}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{0048FF}

\fill[green](0,0)rectangle(7,7);

\fill[red](0,6)rectangle ++(1,1);
\fill[red](2,2)rectangle ++(1,3);
\fill[red](3,3)rectangle ++(2,1);

\fill[blue](1,2)rectangle ++(1,4);

\fill[white](3,4)rectangle ++(2,1);
\fill[white](6,3)rectangle ++(1,1);
\fill[white](5,0)rectangle ++(1,4);

\draw[step =1cm , black, line width=3] (0,0)grid(7,7);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted not only a code snippet (though a relevant one, of course), but made it [immediately compilable](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) by providing instructions such as `\documentclass{<whatever>}`, `\usepackage{any needed packages>}`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. Providing a couple of sentences to explain how your solution works and how it differs from others would also make your posting more helpful. Please consider editing your positing in this manner. (Have a look at the other answers to this posting for some examples.)

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `pxpic` package, you don't even need to do many changes to your original Python format. To get the grid effect you can use one of the examples from its documentation (in the "Miscellaneous" section):

```
\documentclass[border=3.14]{standalone}

\usepackage{pxpic}

\newcommand\gridpxpic[3][]
  {{\setlength\fboxsep{#2}\colorbox{black}{\pxpic[gap-hack=-\fboxsep,#1]{#3}}}}

\begin{document}
\gridpxpic
  [
    colours =
      {
         0 = [HTML]{54ff00}
        ,1 = [HTML]{ffffff}
        ,2 = [HTML]{ff0000}
        ,3 = [HTML]{0048ff}
      }
    ,size = 10pt % size of a single pixel
    ,lines = csv % input method really close to Python output, only remove []
  ]
  {1pt}
  {
    2,0,0,0,0,0,0
    0,3,0,0,0,0,0
    0,3,2,1,1,0,0
    0,3,2,2,2,1,1
    0,3,2,0,0,1,0
    0,0,0,0,0,1,0
    0,0,0,0,0,1,0
  }%
\end{document}
```

[image]

You don't need to use commas in the input though, with `lines=space` you get the lines in the pixel pic delimited by spaces (or newlines which TeX usually treats like spaces):

```
\documentclass[border=3.14]{standalone}

\usepackage{pxpic}

\newcommand\gridpxpic[3][]
  {{\setlength\fboxsep{#2}\colorbox{black}{\pxpic[gap-hack=-\fboxsep,#1]{#3}}}}

\begin{document}
\gridpxpic
  [
    colours =
      {
         0 = [HTML]{54ff00}
        ,1 = [HTML]{ffffff}
        ,2 = [HTML]{ff0000}
        ,3 = [HTML]{0048ff}
      }
    ,size = 10pt % size of a single pixel
    ,lines = space
  ]
  {1pt}
  {
    2000000
    0300000
    0321100
    0322211
    0320010
    0000010
    0000010
  }%
\end{document}
```

(output like above)

Answer (score 2):

If you use pgf's `parser` module you can avoid spamming commas,

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfmodule{parser}

\begin{document}

\def\pixelartinitial{
    \def\pixelartx{0}
    \def\pixelarty{0}
}
\def\pixelartnextrow{% next row = new line = enter
    \def\pixelartx{0}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pixelarty{\pixelarty - 1}
}
\def\pixelartnextpixel#1{% #1 is a color or tikz options
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pixelartx{\pixelartx + 1}
    \fill [#1] (\pixelartx, \pixelarty) rectangle +(1.05, 1.05);
    % 1.05 is overshoot; necessary to avoid white gaps
}
\pgfparserdef{pixel art}{initial}{the letter r}{\pixelartnextpixel{red}}
\pgfparserdef{pixel art}{initial}{the letter b}{\pixelartnextpixel{blue}}
\pgfparserdef{pixel art}{initial}{the letter g}{\pixelartnextpixel{green}}
\pgfparserdef{pixel art}{initial}{the character 0}{\pixelartnextpixel{white!00!black}}
\pgfparserdef{pixel art}{initial}{the character 1}{\pixelartnextpixel{white!10!black}}
\pgfparserdef{pixel art}{initial}{the character 2}{\pixelartnextpixel{white!20!black}}
\pgfparserdef{pixel art}{initial}{the character 3}{\pixelartnextpixel{white!30!black}}
\pgfparserdef{pixel art}{initial}{the character 4}{\pixelartnextpixel{white!40!black}}
\pgfparserdef{pixel art}{initial}{the character 5}{\pixelartnextpixel{white!50!black}}
\pgfparserdef{pixel art}{initial}{the character 6}{\pixelartnextpixel{white!60!black}}
\pgfparserdef{pixel art}{initial}{the character 7}{\pixelartnextpixel{white!70!black}}
\pgfparserdef{pixel art}{initial}{the character 8}{\pixelartnextpixel{white!80!black}}
\pgfparserdef{pixel art}{initial}{the character 9}{\pixelartnextpixel{white!90!black}}
\pgfparserdef{pixel art}{initial}{the character ,}{\pixelartnextrow}
\pgfparserdef{pixel art}{initial}{the character ;}{\pgfparserswitch{final}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm]
    \pixelartinitial
    \pgfparserparse{pixel art}
    133222323323222332332233322332323323333333333333343333323332323223,
    334333345343435444444444444433344333434444444344444443444434443443,
    443454444434554545554454444444444554444455454555455444545545554545,
    344444454445445455343444544444444444544445544454555555545554545455,
    355544445544455555444444445534454445454565555556555554556555545544,
    454555554554465545544445544544445555455555555555455545555545554554,
    445454545565654555445445455545545565555456565565555555555555655554,
    455554444556565655555455545555455555556555565565655565555555555555,
    456545454655556655545555555455555555555665565566555566556555555555,
    355555555455555555655555556456542233556656565555565565556556655555,
    466556655556555566565555655541222233232455565655565565556665555555,
    456555666566655666655655666222322232323235566655565665555556555555,
    456555655665656666656566552223323233222332556655665555656555556565,
    455667656566665666656666532234543323222332356556556566566566555555,
    455676566666566666655667624667665533322233236665656666656555655666,
    455566556666576665666676226777877644323233225666666565656655555556,
    466665566676676766666676246788887653323332223666666666666656555566,
    446677567766666666766764247877877654423323222655565665556666555566,
    466566577666777677656743256787766655433223222435555565565666655555,
    345565465676577777677642367777777766553222222334356555666655565555,
    345435445555556777667523367777776666543322222334344454655655655555,
    234434543444445577766442355467643444333222222234344454456557554444,
    133345444444335457776232335437434232233222222233334434456665555455,
    123344444543344456465433346348536634553222222233333333456656554455,
    234344553453334344435322375477456457653222222223233333356556555444,
    134433444433333333435332367767557876543222222233333323245554554454,
    144333343333333324333322257777556776532222232243545343334445334444,
    143333433433333333322222266767546666433223222222333334345443434443,
    133323333334333333332122245646226755432222222223223333434333324332,
    133323323332423333223222244673345654332222222322223222333322233323,
    223234333323333332323222225465343454432222222223233323223323333233,
    223333333333333332222222215566545554332232221223333223322333233232,
    122233333332232322233222233454444543322322221222233322333322223233,
    223332333333224443233312221257754432222422222122333333233322323323,
    122322234333332343333222221225653222232211222323333333322322232323,
    122223232323323333344222122113222222223322222222232332322333223233,
    122323333333333344444323232111232222332222222112223322233223233333,
    223322222333333444334322223121333333233211122212222322232223222342,
    222232333244344443343322211122254323333321112121233433333333322333,
    223233333444324344423422222222255433343322122222222222433333333323,
    132334444333222243222222212222345444544432212212222212213333332323,
    223344433332332122221222121235666555665433222321121122212333333222,
    132332233323332122212212222555666666676543221221212234434433332223,
    123322333332343221222222224567776766766642232222112223533333332232,
    223323332334322231223222325667777677766543222222122222443433333433,
    232223343333323222231223247778777777776542332112212122223333334233,
    133332234434333232222223357788787787766522222123322122233344344443,
    233232323444432222222223367777887778766533222323433211122232355553,
    233232232333442221222234688778887787677523234324442111112112322333,
    132334232333344323232246777778788888876433324542222111111222233453,
    233233333332233321222227778777888887776433443221111121211122222443,
    223323334343443212212133677777889888875433222221211111211122222223,
    222334443344332232222343336578998787653322122111111111111123222222,
    223334433433222212222223333333557766333322212122211111112213333222,
    223333434333212221222222223333333323322311221322112111111122221222,
    212334343443221221233233222332333234222221222222111111121111222222,
    132223333333222212222222122323322322222221222222231121211112222222,
    121222323333121222222222222322222231221111222122321222211111133222,
    122233433332222122222121222222223111212112221222322321012111112111,
    121244344543222222222211121222232222211222222122221211111112221122,
    222444444532212222222221111211223221111121221222222111111122122311,
    222434445331112122221112222221221122111211222212221221111111112222,
    233333334322222322222221122222121221111211211222212111211222212322,
    222222332221222322222221112211212211111111112121111111111211111112,
    132223321222222111111112122122221121211112211111111111121111121211,
    123233212222323222212111211212122111111211221121111211111111211122,
    122222222423222222221222121121121122121121121111111122111211212212,
    222232222222233313222211121122212212222111111112112211111211221121,
    122222223222222222122212121221111112111111111111111121111111212122,
    222122211222222221211221111111121111111111211211111121112111111222,
    121212213332332211122112211111111111121122121111111122111121111122,
    222221122232222321121221111211111111122122111212111111111112111122,
    222221223342322323212221111111111111121111111112211111111111111122,
    122122222333125523226554111111111111111111111111111111111111111122,
    212221222332252242367655542110111111111111111111111111111111111111,
    112222322222424424666765554552111112111111121211112111111111111221,
    222121222322222223555566655544211112122221111111211111111121111211,
    212222122223331232444555655554433111111111111111111111111121101111,
    111221222222122231333445556656654432111212111121121111111111111111,
    211111221111211212333345455555555532113332232113121111112111111112,
    212111122222222211212344455445324553324332322222221111112111211112,
    221211211211112222144443444544432243332223332231111111111211111111,
    112111112121221123345434334443455223333213222122221201111111111011,
    111111111221111133454543343454245421223222233211112111111101221121,
    121121111211121133554643334345513441211122222222221111111111111112,
    012121112111112233434644332424441333121222212112111111011111111112,
    112111112121111223334543332222332234322121212211211111111121111121,
    112111111221221233344432222122212212212121112111111111111111111111,
    122212211112111213234222222222221121111111111111111111101111112112,
    111222121111111111232222222212222111221111111111111111111111122111,
    121221211211121211132122211122211111111111211111111101111111111112,
    111121111121211122121121112222111221211112121111110111010121111111,
    112111121121121111121111221222121120111211101111111111111111212112,
    111222112111121122112121112111111111111011111111111111110112211111,
    111111112121222212121111211211121111011111101111111111111111110111,
    111122111122112222112111211111111111111111111111011101111111111111,
    111121211211212111111112112111111111111111011101101111101111211111,
    111221111122111121111111111111111111111111111111112110101111111111,
    121111122111121112211112222111111111111111111111111110111111100111,
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: pixel mona liisa]

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is the `PixelArtTikz` package:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{PixelArtTikz}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{base.csv}
2,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,3,0,0,0,0,0
0,3,2,1,1,0,0
0,3,2,2,2,1,1
0,3,2,0,0,1,0
0,0,0,0,0,1,0
0,0,0,0,0,1,0
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\PixlArtTikz[Codes=0123,Colors={green,white,red,blue},Correction]{base.csv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another possible approach using the `pixelart` package:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pixelart}

\begin{document}

\colorbox{black}{%
  \pixelart[
    colors={
      0={green},
      1={white},
      2={red},
      3={blue}
    },
    squares={overlap=-.05}
  ]{
  2000000
  0300000
  0321100
  0322211
  0320010
  0000010
  0000010
  }%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]