# How to use for (or foreach) instead of hardcoding

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, loops

I am new to Tikz and I am trying to draw the following
[image]

So far I did this manually but I was wondering how a foreach-Loop would work.

```
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    %   \def\compOneOne{5}
    %   \def\nodeName{C1}
        node distance = 0pt,
        square/.style = {draw=blue!60, fill=blue!5, very thick, 
            minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em, % <---
            outer sep=0pt},
        square2/.style = {draw=purple!60, fill=blue!5, very thick, 
                minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em, % <---
                outer sep=0pt},
        ]
    
        
        %Nodes
        \node[square]   (a1) {};
        \node[square, right=of a1] (a2) {};
        \node[square, right=of a2] (a3) {};
        \node[square, right=of a3] (a4) {};
        \node[square, below=of a1] (b1) {};
        \node[square, right=of b1] (b2) {};
        \node[square, right=of b2] (b3) {};
        \node[square2, below=of b1] (c1) {};
        \node[square2, right=of c1] (c2) {};
        \node[square2, right=of c2] (c3) {};
        \node[square2, right=of c3] (c4) {};
        \node[square2, below=of c1] (A1) {};
        \node[square2, right=of A1] (A2) {};
        \node[square2, right=of A2] (A3) {};
        \node[square2, right=of A3] (A4) {};
        \node[square2, right=of A4] (A5) {};
        \node[square2, right=of A5] (A6) {};
        \node[square2, right=of A6] (A7) {};
        \node[square2, right=of A7] (A8) {};
        \node[square2, below=of A1] (B1) {};
        \node[square2, right=of B1] (B2) {};
        
%       \node[square2, below=of B1] (C1) {};
%       \foreach \number in {1,...,\compOneOne}{
%           \node[square2, right=of \nodeName] (N-\nodeName) {};
%           \nodeName = N-\nodeName;
%           
%       }
        
    
        
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The stuff that's commented out shows my own attempts on it.
Furthermore I was struggeling with naming conventions and how to rename my variable efficiently.
It would be very nice of you to help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try out this answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/157127/224762). But it is without the use of for or foreach but it you should be able to draw this graph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends if you want to fill your nodes with content afterwards. But at this state, the following code is working with `foreach` loops. It is definitely NOT the best option here, since each line is different. A matrix of nodes should be a better answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance = 0pt,
        square/.style = {draw=blue!60, fill=blue!5, very thick, 
            minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em, % <---
            outer sep=0pt},
        square2/.style = {draw=purple!60, fill=blue!5, very thick, 
                minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em, % <---
                outer sep=0pt},
        ]
    
        \node[square]   (a1) {};
        \foreach \j in {2,3,4}
            {
            \pgfmathsetmacro\i{\j-1}
            \node[square, right=of a\i] (a\j) {};
            }
        
        \node[square, below=of a1] (b1) {};
        \foreach \j in {2,3}
            {
            \pgfmathsetmacro\i{\j-1}
            \node[square, right=of b\i] (b\j) {};
            }

        \node[square2, below=of b1] (c1) {};
        \foreach \j in {2,3,4}
            {
            \pgfmathsetmacro\i{\j-1}
            \node[square2, right=of c\i] (c\j) {};
            }

        \node[square2, below=of c1] (A1) {};
        \foreach \j in {2,...,8}
            {
            \pgfmathsetmacro\i{\j-1}
            \node[square2, right=of A\i] (A\j) {};
            }

        \node[square2, below=of A1] (B1) {};
        \node[square2, right=of B1] (B2) {};       
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**
Since I proposed using a matrix of nodes, here's my solution with it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
    
    \def\wdth{1pt} % line width of your nodes
    \tikzset{ 
    table/.style={
      matrix of nodes,
      row sep=-\wdth,
      column sep=-\wdth,
      nodes={line width=\wdth,rectangle,minimum size=1cm,align=center}
      }
    }
    
    \newcommand{\bs}{|[fill=blue,fill opacity=0.2,draw=blue]|}
    \newcommand{\rs}{|[fill=red,fill opacity=0.2,draw=red]|}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix (mat) [table]
        {
        \bs & \bs  & \bs & \bs  &   &   &   &   \\
        \bs & \bs  & \bs &      &   &   &   &   \\
        \rs & \rs  & \rs & \rs  &   &   &   &   \\
        \rs & \rs  & \rs & \rs  &   \rs & \rs  & \rs & \rs  \\
        \rs & \rs  &    &   &   &   &   &   \\
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Matrix of nodes]