# tikz: how to set one style to values of another style?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

I have a pixel grid consisting of dashed lines, and I want to set a pixel using `minimum size`.

As can be seen, I set the minimum size manually, which works.  However, I would like to set it to another, inherited style key.  How can I do that?  The (naive) commented-out code doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{
  grid lines/.style={
    line width=0.5pt,
    dashed,
    step=5mm},
  pixel/.style={
    grid lines,
    solid,
    draw,
%   minimum size=\pgfkeysvalueof{step},
    minimum size=5mm,
    fill}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[grid lines] (0,0) grid (1,1);
  \node[pixel] at (0.25,0.25) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: If you draw it as well as filling it then it will naturally expand by half the line width, which should be the right amount to cover the dashes.

Comment: OK, I could inherit the `line width` property from `grid lines`.  However, how can I assign the `grid lines/step` property to `pixel/minimum size`?  I've now simplified the question.

Comment: Simplest way is to have keys that save those details, say `pixel/line width` and `pixel/size` which then the `grid lines` and `pixel` styles use.  So rather than try to read from a separate style, you effectively have a "parent" style that sets both.

Comment: Well, yes.  There are a lot of practical solutions; for example, I could do `\def\gridStep{5mm}` and use this value in both styles.  Still, this is far from elegant IMHO.  The right way would really be assign one key value to another key, and I wonder how this can be done – actually, I can't believe that I'm the first person who wants to do something along this way...

Comment: +1: Out of interest, what is the actual use case?

Comment: The actual use-case is to draw a simple, magnified bitmap (for example, the letter 'A'  at a size of 12px) for documentation purposes.

Comment: Interesting. And how would you provide the pattern data?

Comment: I follow the answer of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/157127/20911 that uses `\def\pixels{...}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to dig into the code to see how `step` works and read back the magic numbers (`\tikz@grid@x` and `\tikz@grid@y`) but I'd recommend a different approach in which you set those parameters using separate keys which you then use in both pieces.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/660910/86}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{
  pixel/line width/.initial=0.5pt,
  pixel/size/.initial=5mm,
  grid lines/.style={
    line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pixel/line width},
    dashed,
    step=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pixel/size}
  },
  pixel/.style={
    solid,
    draw,
    line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pixel/size},
    minimum size=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pixel/line width},
    inner sep=0pt,
    fill}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[grid lines] (0,0) grid (1,1);
  \node[pixel] at (0.25,0.25) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: grid with filled in square]

Comment: Aaah, thanks!  Yes, this looks very nice.

Comment: +1: First time I see **.is family**

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Too bad its effect will be overwritten by `pixel/.style`. (`pixel/.is family` is a shortcut to a faster version of `pixel/.style={/tikz/pixel/.cd}`.)

Comment: I get in the habit of using `.is family` whenever I define a sub-family of keys.  I'll remove it as it is redundant here.

Answer (score 2):

The `\pgfkeysvalueof` macro only works with actual value-keys.

Due to, I guess, legacy reasons, the keys `xstep` and `ystep` just define another macro (here `\tikz@grid@x` and `\tikz@grid@y`) even though they could as well have been value-keys.

And `step` just sets these two macros to the same value? No, because it also allows a value in the form of a coordinate (starting with `(`) and sets the xstep to that coordinate's *x* value and the ystep to that coordinate's *y* value.

Even if we find a way to retrieve the value that has been given to one of these keys, one needs to think about how to deal with `step = (15:1cm)`.

---

Well, you can always add more stuff to an already existing key, say,

```
@step/.initial=1cm,
step/.append style={/tikz/@step={#1}}
```

and then `\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/@step}` returns the value that was given to `step` last (which might as well have been `(15:1cm)`!).

---

We could re-write how `xstep`, `ystep` and `step` work:

```
\tikzset{
  xstep/.initial=1cm,
  ystep/.initial=1cm,
}
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@step@single#1{%
  \pgfkeyssetvalue{/tikz/xstep}{#1}%
  \pgfkeyssetvalue{/tikz/ystep}{#1}}
\def\tikz@step@point#1{%
  \pgf@process{#1}%
  \pgfkeyssetevalue{/tikz/xstep}{\the\pgf@x}%
  \pgfkeyssetevalue{/tikz/ystep}{\the\pgf@y}}
\def\tikz@grid@x{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/xstep}}
\def\tikz@grid@y{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ystep}}
\makeatother
```

and now you can use `\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/xstep}`/`\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ystep}` …
but then you still have the case of `step = 1` since TikZ allows dimension-less units to be used with the xy coordinate system. (Dimension-less units in `minimum size` will be interpreted as `pt`.)

In your case, you are explicitly using `step=5mm` and putting `grid lines` inside `pixel` so you're side-stepping all these problems but I want to highlight how complex this can get when you factor in all general possibilities and use cases.

---

All that to say that Andrew Stacey's solution is a much cleaner way to this and give you (or your users) much better control over what gets drawn. Just don't forget to use only dimensions with units for `pixel/size`.

Comment: Thanks!  I miss such comments in the TikZ manual...