Conflict between ngerman and stringstrings packages
A TeX distribution upgrade broke a small project of mine, and it took me a while but I finally figured out that the problems are due to a conflict between the ngerman package and the stringstrings package.
Here is a MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{stringstrings}

\newcommand{\test}[1]{
  \typeout{Arg: #1}
  \convertchar[q]{#1}{,}{ }
  \typeout{thestring: \thestring}
  \thestring
}
\begin{document}

\test{0,1}   % Works fine
\test{[0,0]} % Causes error

\end{document}

When I run this, I get a pretty long output from the second typeout, because \thestring ends up containing the error repeated many times, but ultimately the problem is the following:
! ngerman: The command "\rotatingword is undefined.
\thestring ...command "\rotatingword is undefined}
                                                  ``{Use `` for a simple dou...
l.14 \test{[0,0]}

If I comment out the ngerman package, the problem goes away, though in my project I need it. Any ideas on why this happens, and/or how to solve it, are appreciated!

You wrote, "in my project I need [the ngerman package]". No you don't. The ngerman package is obsolete. Don't use it. Instead, employ \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}.

Note that ngerman  package was last updated in 1998 and has been deprecated in favour of babel  since LaTeX2e was introduced in 1993.

Is your aim to replace commas with spaces? Or is this just an example? In the latter case, can you be a bit more specific? There are much better ways to do the task than with stringstrings. Anyway, as others have already commented, ngerman is obsolete, deprecated and conflicts with several packages..

Ok thanks! I replaced ngerman with babel and the ngerman option, seems all good!
@egreg my actual macro is a not so trivial beast that given a string like [[1,0], [0,1]] creates an fcolorbox-based "pixel"-image with a black diagonal (loosely based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/157102 )

I’m voting to close this question because the OP's issue was solved in the comments.

@Mico how can I do that? Just deleting it?

No need to delete your query. It's not a bad query; it's just that your issue's been solved.

This question is similar to: mathabx conflicts ngerman?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
